# SIP server ("gateway") for joining accounts

Tags: voip, gateway, sip

I have a phone supporting 2 accounts, but I need 4 accounts. Is it possible to install some sort of SIP server/gateway/proxy (on a linux server), that would register those 4 accounts and I would be able to connect to it as if it was 1 account? (With dialing rules, etc.) 3 of the accounts have incoming numbers.

Thanks.

Tomas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

- [asteriskNOW](http://www.asterisk.org/asterisknow) - very flexible, web interface configuration
- [trixbox](http://www.trixbox.com/products/trixbox-ce) - asterisk based, should be more user friendly for beginners
- [FreeSwitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/) - alternative to asterisk, configuration only via XML files

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend AsteriskNow - very simple to deploy, just google it, download the ISO, burn to a CD and boot your server and it installs everything you need.

We looked at a few alternatives and found AsteriskNow one of the more actively maintained all-in-one solutions compared to e.g. Trixbox

I'd also make sure you

- set up something like fail2ban to
  make sure you detect (and block)
  people trying to hack into your SIP
  account
- configure a firewall such as 
  IPTables to block any inbound traffic
  you don't want - I only expose SIP
  and IAX2 on our external NIC.